# RxSwift How to add "clear all" UIButton to simple spreadsheet example

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Here's the code from the RxSwift repo for a simple spreadsheet (adding three numbers):

```
Observable.combineLatest(number1.rx_text, number2.rx_text, number3.rx_text) { textValue1, textValue2, textValue3 -> Int in
        return (Int(textValue1) ?? 0) + (Int(textValue2) ?? 0) + (Int(textValue3) ?? 0)
    }
    .map { $0.description }
    .bindTo(result.rx_text)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

I want to add a "Clear all" UIButton, that will cause the three boxes to be reset to zero and the total also set to zero. In imperative style, very easy.

What is the correct way of adding this button in RxSwift?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways off the top of my head.

## Imperative

```
button.rx_tap
    .subscribeNext { [weak self] _ in
        self?.number1.text = ""
        self?.number2.text = ""
        self?.number3.text = ""
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Note however, that this will not update the `combineLatest` `Observable` below until you change focus between fields. I haven't looked into why.

## Using `Variables`

```
// Declared as a property
let variable1 = Variable<String>("")

// Back down in `viewDidLoad`
number1.rx_text
    .bindTo(variable1)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

variable1.asObservable()
    .bindTo(number1.rx_text)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

button.rx_tap
    .subscribeNext { [weak self] _ in
        self?.variable1.value = ""
        // and other variables as well..
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

Observable.combineLatest(variable1.asObservable(), ....
```

I've omitted showing the same code for `variable2` and `variable3`, as you should probably make a two-way binding helper method if you go this route.