# bindTo rx_text of a UITextField did not trigger the UITextField's emit event

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm a new one to learn RxSwift.

I modified the Simple Numbers example in the RxSwift Example App, which will add three numbers into a result number.

I add a `testStr` `UITextField`, and an `upperCase` `UILabel`. I map `testStr` to uppercase and `bindTo` the `upperCase` label, that's good. And I also map `testStr` to its `length`, and `bindTo` the `num1` field. Strange things happen, although the contents of the `num1` field changes, it does not emit any event, so it has no effect on the `result` label. Even if I input some number into another number field, the `result` number does not count the `num1`.

Have I made any wrong use of `bindTo`? In what way can I make the `num1` emit an event?

Thanks!!!

```
@IBOutlet weak var num1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var num2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var num3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var testStr: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var upperCase: UILabel!

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Observable.combineLatest(num1.rx_text, num2.rx_text, num3.rx_text) {
        (textval1, textval2, textval3) -> Int in
            return (Int(textval1) ?? 0) + (Int(textval2) ?? 0) + (Int(textval3) ?? 0)
        }
        .map{$0.description}
        .bindTo(result.rx_text)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    let obStr = testStr.rx_text

    obStr
        .map {$0.uppercaseString}
        .bindTo(upperCase.rx_text)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    obStr
        .map{ $0.characters.count }
        .map{ $0.description }
        .bindTo(num1.rx_text)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `Subject` such as `Variable` to store the value.  You can see an example of this in [this answer in the section called **Using `Variables`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201532/rxswift-how-to-add-clear-all-uibutton-to-simple-spreadsheet-example/38202206#38202206).

The reason it doesn't work is because `rx_text` will only omit a next element when it's changed by the user, **not** programmatically (as you're doing). This is because `rx_text` is really using this method from `UIControl` to get notified of changes to the field:

```
public class UIControl : UIView {
    public func addTarget(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector, forControlEvents controlEvents: UIControlEvents)
}
```

However, that method does not call the `action` method on `target` when the change happens programmatically.  **Only** when it happens due to a **user** changing something.

So, you should see a next event if you were to change the field programmatically and then the user were to tap into (or out of) the field.  However, that's not what you want.

Instead, refer to that answer I linked you to and it will work.